# Setting v-select default value with if conditions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, vuetify.js

I have a dropdown menu where I want the default value to be set based on the login usertype.

I have the this page to appear after login, and I want the v-select option choice to be chosen according to the usertype condition and store the select value in localStorage. I put the if conditions in method, but the v-select default value still is shown as null. How can I pass and store the default value based on the usertype conditions when login and refresh.

```
#vue 2.6 vuetify 2.3
<template>
  <h1>title</h1>
  <v-select 
    :items:"items"
    v-model:"select"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['A','B'],
      select: localStorage.getItem('select'),
    };
  },
  watch: {
    selected(value) {
      localStorage.setItem('select', value);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('select'));
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.selectChoice();
  },
  methods: {
    selectChoice() {
      if (this.users.types>=0) {
         this.select = 'A';
      }
      else if (this.users.types>=2) {
         this.select = 'B';
      }

    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code, you are watching `selected`, but the variable is named `select`. Also, where does `this.users` come from? You use it in `selectChoice()`, but there is no other reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
  <v-select 
    :items:"items"
    v-model:"select"
  ></v-select>
```

should be

```
  <v-select 
    :items="items"
    v-model="select"
  ></v-select>
```

and

```
watch: {
    select(value) {  // instead of selected
      localStorage.setItem('select', value);
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('select'));
    },
}
```

Also, `this.users` is not defined and should throw an js exception.